# puppeteer "copy as cURL"

Tags: puppeteer, playwright

Are there any ways to `Copy as cURL (bash)` with puppeteer or playwright?

[image]

Comment: I think it shouldn't be that hard to build that manually, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. As suggested by the commenter, you can easily write something to take a [route](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-route) to curl. A route encapsulates both the request and subsequent response within playwright.

However, there is also an easier, more direct way by leveraging the [HAR](https://w3c.github.io/web-performance/specs/HAR/Overview.html) file format.

- Tell playwright to [record](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#recording-har-with-a-script) a `.har`, optionally filtering to only a subset of URLs you care about.
- Load the `.har` into a HAR -> cURL converter tool like [this](https://mattcg.github.io/har-to-curl/).